# JSon to CSV with Java using CDL: possible to replace comma-sep. by semi-colum sep. values?

Tags: java, json, csv, separator

Everything is in the title :)

I'm using org.json.CDL to convert JSONArray into CSV data but it renders a string with ',' as separator.
I'd like to know if it's possible to replace with ';' ?

Here is a simple example of what i'm doing:

```
public String exportAsCsv() throws Exception {
    return CDL.toString(
            new JSONArray(
                    mapper.writeValueAsString(extractAccounts()))
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice on that question.

Edit: No replacement solution of course, as this could have impact for large data, and of course the library used enable me to specify the field separator.

Edit2: Finally the solution to extract data as JSONArray (and String...) was not very good, especially for large data file.

So i made the following changes:

- use a Java CSV library (for example: http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php)
- refactor code to stream data from json input source to csv output source

This is nicer for large data treatment. If you have comments do not hesitate.

Answer (score 1):

```
String output = "Hello,This,is,separated,by,a,comma";
// Simple call the replaceAll method.
output = output.replace(',',';');
```

I found this in the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

**Example**

```
String value = "Hello,tthis,is,a,string";
value = value.replace(',', ';');
System.out.println(value);

// Outputs: Hello;tthis;is;a;string
```

Comment: Yep of course this works.. but that's a dirty solution, i'm looking for something nicer as configuration instead of replacement.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work, as quoted commas shouldn't be replaced.

Comment: A CSV file can contain comma inside values. In this case the value must be enclosed by double quotes. See [RFC 4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180). And I guess the OP doesn't want values containing comma to be modified.

Comment: Apologies. I guess we could have a regex statement to ensure there are no quotes.

Comment: Thanks for answers, finally i've chosen a nicer solution for CSV generation. Solution given as Edit in original post